# swift iOS 11.2 WKWebView doesn't show up

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to implement a simple web browser in my application.
Because I need to control cookies, I decided to go with WKWebView.

The official example works well, but that example 1) doesn't use storyboard 2) sets view to webview directly

So I added my WKWeView to storyboard and connected to an outlet, then loads an URL in `viewDidLoad`:

```
class BrowserViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("browser view loaded")
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.youku.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

My Storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

However, when I run my app in the simulator, the WKWebView does not appear:

[image]

How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

This is the layout and constraints of the view

[image]

**UPDATE:**

So I removed all the unnecessary constraints and the layout seems to be fixed. However, the web view is still blank.

If I add a line `view = webView` at the end of `viewDidLoad`. The web page renders correctly.

(For some reason the images would upload, I'll try again later)

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately, move everything to `viewWillAppear` doesn't work either.

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("browser view loaded")

        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.bing.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
```

Webview is still blank.

Comment: Have you added constraints to your webView? It could be that it has loaded but that it is simply not visible on the screen because it's location isn't correct. Your search bar appears to have shifted so the webView might have done the same thing.

Comment: Yes, the webview and the toolbar is in a stack view. And both has the normal constraints, i.e. top, bottom, leading, trailing

Comment: To confirm the issue is related to autolayout or not, disable autolayout for the controller and see if it is visible.

Comment: I don't know how to turn it off. Google doesn't show a clear way to do it either. If I remove all the constraints, is auto layout considered disabled?

Comment: add webView programatically, not through storyboard or xib

Comment: I'll try that. Is there any reason why storyboard doesn't work?

Comment: @MuhammedIrfan Could you elaborate a little bit on how to add webView programmatically? I tried `view.addSubView(webView)` and `stackView.addSubView(webView)`, neither worked. The simulator shows the same screen as the original question.

Comment: Just to make sure, try loading the webView request in viewDidAppear. Might be an issue with the constraints and frames not yet set up in viewDidLoad. Give it a try.

Comment: Sorry for late response @YuanFu, here is the link for example: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview?changes=_8

Answer (score 0):

Delete IBOutlet and try connect to an outlet again.

May be

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        print("browser view loaded")
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.youku.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}

extension ViewController: WKUIDelegate {

}

extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is very strange. I removed the oulet and added again, but nothing changed. It seems the code is correct? I wonder where did I do wrong...

Comment: Try Stack View
Axis is Vertical

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is related to the StackView options. Please show also what settings did you set to your StackView? Alignment and Distribution are the main things.

Try setting:

`Alignment -> Center
Distribution -> Fill`

Remove all constraints from Toolbar and WebView, and leave only the Toolbar Height = 56. That is the only constraint needed inside the StackView. Also, make sure you leave the StackView's constraints, as those define the constraints for the objects contained inside.
Make sure there are no red borders around your views (if it is red, then you're missing something).

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question. There is still something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to make it work, but the reason behind it remains a mystery.

Apparently, if I move the WKWebView out of the stack view, it renders the web page just fine.

[image: layout]

[image: screen]

P.S. the url is changed to https://www.bing.com

Comment: It definitely was the conflicting/insufficient constraint issue. Either you had conflicting constraints that dragged the web view out of the view region or you did not specify the **Distribution** and **Alignment** property of the stack view correctly.